# How to list versions of installed QtQuick modules

Tags: qt

Is there an quick way to determine the versions of the installed QtQuick modules someone has?

I can find the modules in the QML path, and e.g. for the Layouts module I can find in the `Layouts/plugins.qmltypes` some commentary eluding to the version of that module ....

```
...
// This file was auto-generated by:
// 'qmlplugindump -nonrelocatable QtQuick.Layouts 1.12'
....
```

So I can see from this file that Layouts 1.12 is installed. But surely there is a better way to go about listing all the versions of all the installed modules?

Thanks!